# Expo debug log throwing error at transform function on build

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

I'm trying to set up an expo app using react and I can't get past this error I keep getting when it is trying to build the Javascript Bundle.

```
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js: Transformer.transform is not a function
node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js: Transformer.transform is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check React Native and Metro versions compatibility.
I had the same issue with these versions :

```
"react-native": "^0.63.3"
"metro": "^0.61.0",
"metro-core": "^0.61.0"
```

And this works :

```
"react-native": "^0.63.3"
"metro": "^0.58.0",
"metro-core": "^0.58.0"
```